# No sound detection in audio jack Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, sound-card, headphone-jack

I use Windows 10 and I am having a problem.

I have a piano that supports audio output. It worked fine with my headphones. But now, I have a problem. I thought to record my piano voice on PC with the AUX cable to reduce background noise. I installed the software required but the software did not detect any voice. As soon as I put in the AUX cable, the microphone of my laptop stops as it is a combo jack. For reference, I have earphones with a mic in them. And the input works well.

Is there problem with the software or I am using the wrong sound drivers? If any other info is required, kindly ask me.

Thank You.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong kind of aux cable.

Comment: But the aux cable works when i use it to send sound from phone to piano.

Comment: Yes, but there are several types of audio sockets on a PC. You need a plug which matches the socket. TRS vs TRRS. See [Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks - Cable Chick Blog](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/)